# Android/Eclipse Installation on MacOSX - adb is not working

Tags: android, failed-installation, android-sdk-tools

Computer Details:
Macbook, Late 2008
Apple Mac OS X 10.7.3 Intel

Eclipse Details:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

I'm unable to install or run adb on my machine and I wish to resolve this issue.

After I re-installed my ADT plugin on Eclipse and re-download a new AndroidSDK zip file,
I ran the Android SDK Manager plugin and I proceeded to download the platform-tools where adb is contained.

This is the log message I received:

```
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11
Stopping ADB server succeeded.
Starting ADB server succeeded.
Done. 1 package installed.
Done loading packages.
```

I went to my directory in bash:

```
/Users/Tapehead/Documents/Android/platform-tools
```

And I tried running various adb shell commands but all I get is:

```
-bash: adb: command not found
```

Which I think it means it isn't installed properly.

Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put

> /Users/Tapehead/Documents/Android/platform-tools

into your PATH in .profile or .bashrc with somethin like this command:

```
export PATH=~/Documents/Android/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the path to `android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools` in your PATH environment variable. In your `~/.profile` file add the line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
```